# python invalid syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

ive just tried running my python script and getting invalid syntax error i've double checked the problem and still cant see the problem can any see the problem? Below is the code if anyone can help see the problem.

thanks.

```
import random
import Tkinter

class life (Tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("The Game Of Life")
        self.grid = [[False for j in range (y)] for i in range (x)]
        universe = Tkinter.Frame(self)
        def createButton (i,j):
            bitmap=None
            if self.grid[i][j]:bitmap ='gray75'
            gridEntry = Tkinter.Button(universe, bitmap=bitmap)
            gridEntry.grid(row=i, column =j)
        self._applyToEachCellOfGrid (createButton)
        universe.pack(side='top')
        scale= Tkinter.Scale(self, orient = Tkinter.HORIZONTAL, from_=1, to =10,
                             command=self.setPeriod)
        scale.pack(side='top')
        quit=Tkinter.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        quit.pack(side='left')
        run=Tkinter.Button(self, text='Run' , command=self.run)
        run.pack(side='right')
        pause=Tkinter.Button(self, text='Pause', command=self.pause)
        pause.pack(side='right')
        self.pack()

    def _applyToEachCellOfGrid (self, function) :
        for i in range (len(self.grid)):
            for j in range (len(self.grid[i])):
                function(i,j)

    def populateGridRandomly(self,x):
        random.seed()
        def setRandomly(i,j):
            if random.random()<x:self.grid[i][j]= True
        self._applyToEachCellOfGrid(setRandomly)

    def calculateNextGeneration(self):
        newGrid=[[ False for j in range ( len (self.grid[i]))] for i in range ( len (self.grid))]
        def calculateLiveness(x,y):
            count = 0
            for i in range (x-1, x+2):
                if 0 <=i<len (self.grid[i]):
                    if ((i !=x)or(j !=y)) and self.grid[i][j]:count +=1
            if self.grid[x][y]:return 2 <= count <=3
            else: return count ==3
        def setNewGrid(x,y):
            newGrid[x][y]= calculateLiveness(x,y)
        self._applyToEachCellOfGrid (setNewGrid)
        self.grid = newGrid

    def pause(self):
        print 'pause called.'

    def run(self):
        print 'run called'

    def setPeriod (self, value):
        print 'setPeriod called with value' , value

if __name__ =="__main__':
    game=Life(8,10)
    game.mainloop()
```

Comment: And the error message?

Comment: typo at the bottom: it should be "__main__" and not "__main__'

Comment: allender, when i run the module comes up with "invalid syntax error"

Comment: Also, `life` != `Life`

Comment: @user125697: erm.. I'm not sure that he does.

Comment: i tried adding the : and still getting the same error and changed the "main" part

Comment: @user1957509: Error type, error message and the line number is the minimum you should post. Preferably the entire trace (unless most of it is irrelevant, but if you're still struggling with syntax errors that may not be for you to decide).

Answer (score 5):

If you use an opening `"`, you have to use a closing `"` as well, not `'`:

```
  File "synt2.py", line 63
    if __name__ =="__main__':
                            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: and this is not the only syntax error he has got

Comment: @Johnny: there are other mistakes, but after correcting this I get no syntax errors in Python 2.  What are you referring to?

Comment: NameError: name 'Life' is not defined (line 64)

Comment: @Johnny: a `NameError` is, well, a `NameError`, not a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Ok you are right, just a letter that should be upper case :)

Comment: johnny, which letter needs to be uppercase

Comment: Well, neither of them is an `InvalidSyntaxError`, which you only get when asking Python to contemplate the perl language.

Comment: At the beginning he wrote `class life` but it should be `class Life`

Comment: i can still not get my code to run in python after fixing the errors

Comment: have a look at my answer

Comment: johnny, i copied the new code you posted and still came up with the error which python version are you using?

Comment: johnny, runs in python 2.7 when runs comes up with "setperiod called with value 1"

Comment: johnny, that has sorted the problem thank you very much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

here is your code, working.

```
import random
import Tkinter

class Life (Tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("The Game Of Life")
        self.grid = [[False for j in range (y)] for i in range (x)]
        universe = Tkinter.Frame(self)
        def createButton (i,j):
            bitmap=None
            if self.grid[i][j]:bitmap ='gray75'
            gridEntry = Tkinter.Button(universe, bitmap=bitmap)
            gridEntry.grid(row=i, column =j)
        self._applyToEachCellOfGrid (createButton)
        universe.pack(side='top')
        scale= Tkinter.Scale(self, orient = Tkinter.HORIZONTAL, from_=1, to =10,
                             command=self.setPeriod)
        scale.pack(side='top')
        quit=Tkinter.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        quit.pack(side='left')
        run=Tkinter.Button(self, text='Run' , command=self.run)
        run.pack(side='right')
        pause=Tkinter.Button(self, text='Pause', command=self.pause)
        pause.pack(side='right')
        self.pack()

    def _applyToEachCellOfGrid (self, function) :
        for i in range (len(self.grid)):
            for j in range (len(self.grid[i])):
                function(i,j)

    def populateGridRandomly(self,x):
        random.seed()
        def setRandomly(i,j):
            if random.random()<x:self.grid[i][j]= True
        self._applyToEachCellOfGrid(setRandomly)

    def calculateNextGeneration(self):
        newGrid=[[ False for j in range ( len (self.grid[i]))] for i in range ( len (self.grid))]
        def calculateLiveness(x,y):
            count = 0
            for i in range (x-1, x+2):
                if 0 <=i<len (self.grid[i]):
                    if ((i !=x)or(j !=y)) and self.grid[i][j]:count +=1
            if self.grid[x][y]:return 2 <= count <=3
            else: return count ==3
        def setNewGrid(x,y):
            newGrid[x][y]= calculateLiveness(x,y)
        self._applyToEachCellOfGrid (setNewGrid)
        self.grid = newGrid

    def pause(self):
        print 'pause called.'

    def run(self):
        print 'run called'

    def setPeriod (self, value):
        print 'setPeriod called with value' , value

if __name__ =="__main__":
    game=Life(8,10)
    game.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared a class named `life`, while you are calling `Life`. Python is case-sensitive. Either change line 4 to to `class Life (Tkinter.Frame):` or change line 64 to `game=life(8,10)`.